# [新機能の提案]自分が投稿した内容が更新されたらWeb Notificationで通知を出す

Tags: 機能の要求, 却下

Stackoverflowで自分が投稿した内容(回答、質問 他)が更新されたらWeb Notificationを使ってブラウザに通知を出すというのはいかがでしょうか?

[自分の質問に回答が寄せられたら通知], [自分の回答が承認されたら通知]など細かく設定できるといいかもしれません。

もちろん、デフォルトでは無効です。

いかがでしょうか?

Comment: 第三者のプラグインはすでにあります：https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/desktop-notifications-for/ijglncoabcgieiokjmgdogpefdblmnle（Chromeのみ）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

当サイトの利用者は主に３つのカテゴリで分けられます：

1. 検索でヒットした質問・回答を読むだけの人
2. アカウントを持っているが、あまり参加しない人
3. 週１回以上参加するユーザー

新機能の要求は主に３番目のグループから来ます。サイトに慣れたユーザーは既にサイトの機能を使いこなしているので、足りない点を追加してほしいと言います。が、それ以外のグループはサイトの機能を使いこなせていないので、機能を追加すると混乱するおそれがあります。

例えば Facebook には沢山の機能があり、なんでもできそうです。しかしそれを探すのが難しい上、どのような動きになるのかも分かりづらいです。

あまり機能は増やさず、ユーザーがそれを作れるようにする、というのが当サイトの考え方です。[API](http://api.stackexchange.com/)があることはご存じですか？英語になりますが、APIを利用することで通知を受け取ることができます。当ネットワークの[StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/notifier)というサイトには様々な通知アプリが登録されていますし、コメントで書いたように[Chromeプラグイン](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/desktop-notifications-for/ijglncoabcgieiokjmgdogpefdblmnle)もあります。

現在の通知機能があるため、このリクエストは[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)にします。もし質問等あれば、ご教示ください。